# Encoder and My Challenges on Digital Logic

Tags: cpu-architecture, encoder, digital-logic, vlsi, digital-design

in following `Encoder`, the priority of `bigger` number is bigger. if the initial state is `0`, after how many `clock pulse`, `Q after being 1`, change states to `zero`.

[image]

My professor, say (3), why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At initial state:
`Q = 0, D1D0 = 00, Q' = 1, JK = 00` encoder input:`0001`

After 1st clock pulse,

`D1D0 = 01`  encoder input:`0011` so `JK =01` resets output `Q = 0, Q' =1`

After 2nd clock pulse,

`D1D0 = 10` encoder input:`0101`  So `JK =10` sets output  `Q = 1, Q' =0`

After 3rd clock pulse,

`D1D0 = 11` encoder input:`1110` So `JK = 11`. toggles the output.

or `Q` switches from `1` to `0`.